# Server error in '/' application: The resource cannot be found, but was working previously (Redirect issue?)

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis, tfs, resources

I had a website that was running locally in iis. I had retrieved it from tfs initially and set it up locally, and it was running. I recently got a new computer, so I had to set up the project again. I followed the same steps as before, getting the code from tfs, and I made sure that I set it up the same in iis. I noted the physical path that I had set the old one too, and made sure that it was set to the same path on my new machine. However, when I try to go to any url including the homepage (just localhost:80), I get the Resource Not Found error.

Everything is the same in iis, so it must be something in the web config that I missed, but I don't know what it would be. When I go to a specific path like localhost/templates/default.aspx, I'm able to load that page, but the urls associated with the site don't seem to be working.

Comment: are you sure that you setup IIS correctly on the new machine.. did you check to make sure that virtual directory's etc..are setup just like the old project.. also did you make sure to start IIS for the default website where you setup your website also check to make sure that you are not using a port in the web project double check all settings new against old..

Comment: So you're saying `localhost/templates/default.aspx` is working? But not `localhost/templates/`?

Comment: Have you verified the application pool information I.e .net version is the same as the original setup?

Comment: Have you verified the application is defined as an application within IIS?

Answer (score 0):

What is the main reason for matching directory structure? Fear of two people working on the same site and it not working on another machine? That will only happen if you hard code in full directory paths rather than using relative links.

Next, why the difficulty setting up the site when you pull from TFS? You can check out code from TFS and then switch to IIS. As long as you keep the virtual directory the same, you won't step on other people that are working on the site. Yes, the physical directory may be better as the same on every machine, but that is not critical. The logical (virtual) location is all you should be concerned about.

More than likely, your attempting to get everything the same is where you messed things up. To check this, manually type in a page and ensure it works. Copy the URI out of the address bar and paste in notepad or Word. On the next line, do the same after failing to click a link to the same page. More than likely there is a small difference.